# Android SqLite Exception on create Table

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, mobile

**Edit-Well I fixed the problem that I was facing as comma was the issue in the query, but now I am not getting the required output i.e when I add a new info to the db it doesn't get displayed(printed) in the text view. Can you guys please check whether there's a bug in the printDatabase() function(although I am not getting errors in log-cat monitor).**

### MainActivity.java

### Products.java file

```
 package com.instinctcode.sqlitesample;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText buckysInput;
TextView buckysText;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buckysInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.buckysInput);
    buckysText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.buckysText);
    dbHandler= new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
    printDatabase();

}
public void addButtonClicked(View view){
    Products product=new Products(buckysInput.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.addProduct(product);
    printDatabase();
}
public void deleteButtonClicked(View view)
{
    String inputText=buckysInput.getText().toString();
    dbHandler.deleteProduct(inputText);
    printDatabase();
}

 public void printDatabase(View v){
String dbString =dbHandler.databaseToString();
buckysText.setText(dbString);
buckysInput.setText("");
}

}



public class Products {
private int _id;
private String _productname;


public Products(String productname) {
    this._productname = productname;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void set_productname(String _productname) {
    this._productname =_productname;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String get_productname() {
    return _productname;
}
```

}

### MyDbHandler.java

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATAVASE_VERSION=2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="products.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS="products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID ="_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
onCreate(db);
}
public void addProduct(Products product){
  ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public void deleteProduct(String productName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";");
}
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString ="";
    SQLiteDatabase db= getWritableDatabase();
    String query= "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_PRODUCTS+ "WHERE 1";

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast())
    {
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"))!=null)
        {
            dbString +=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";

        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

}

Comment: use follow query :  String query="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
            ");";

Answer (score 6):

Comma `,` is missing:

```
CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, productname TEXT )
                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query with this..

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String query="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
")";
db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327975/5208657 well this worked for me. A comma was missing after the AUTO INCREMENT statement, and that caused the error. But still I haven't been able to successfully print the results after adding the product info to the sqlite db (although I am not getting any errors in the monitor).